# many create object url makes my system memory no responsible

Tags: javascript, html, web, memory, blob

I want to make a sound streaming application.

- I write a website that has a media recorder that record a blob every 3 seconds
- Also write a websocket to send its bytes to another client
- The client receives the bytes and URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([bytes]))
- But a problem happens that is on the memory after a while

For instance after five minutes of calling create object url browser memory is increased by 400 MB.

There are any other way than createObjectURL for memory performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve the memory leak by calling the below, after you are done using it.

```
URL.revokeObjectURL(objectURL)
```